# How to use ngModel in Ionic 6

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, ngmodel

I'm using the latest version of Ionic (6.10.0). For the life of me, I cannot get ngModel bindings to work. I have also tried using FormBuilder, but I get a weird error that the property `id` cannot be found (and ngModel is slicker for my uses). Could you provide insight?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks,
Jackson

Comment: Your ngModel is not *appName* it is just *name* you must update your template

Comment: @nevzatopcu Although this is true, that does still not fix the issue. (I just tried)